# Master / Detail Functionality in kogrid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I want to implement Master / Detail Functionality  in kogrid. So that when I select any field of first grid table all the other details will be shown in next detail grid.
Can anybody have any hint how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A create a master/detail grid set you need to use a ko.computed to select/filter the detail.

You need 3 observable arrays and 1 computed.

```
var model = {
  parent: ko.observableArray(),
  details: ko.observableArray(),
  selectedParents: ko.observableArray()
};

model.selectedDetails = ko.computed( function() {
  var selectedParent = this.selectedParents()[0];

  if ( !selectedParent ) {
    return [];
  }

  return this.details().filter( function(item) {
    // define filter comparison here
  } );
}, model );
```

In your markup, define 2 koGrids

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { 
  data: parent, 
  multiSelect: false, 
  selectedItems: selectParents }"></div>

<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: selectedDetails } "></div>
```

koGrid will populate the selectedItems observableArray with Zero or One item.  The computed will execute a filter over the children which the second grid is bound to.

I have omitted the columnDef data bind part from breivity.

If you have an AJAX query to run for the details array, then use a subscription against the "parent" observable, change selectDetails to a straight observableArray and set its contents in the AJAX callback

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd6m3/) for a basic example

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, I got the logic to go ahead,it was very useful.